# Trying to run legacy executables from powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am looking to run net.exe from a script and I am having some trouble with spaces.  Here is the code...

```
# Variables
$gssservers = Import-Csv "gssservers.csv"

$gssservers | Where-Object {$_.Tier -match "DB"} | Foreach-Object {
    net.exe use "\\"$_.Name '/user:'$_.Name'\Administrator' $_.Pass
    $sqlcheck = sc.exe \\$gsssql[1] query "WUAUSERV"
    }
```

When I set line 5 to Write-Host I see that there are spaces that are added outside of anywhere I have quotes which is breaking the net.exe command.  How can I remove those spaces?

For anyone questioning how I am doing this, the net.exe command is the only way I can get to these machines as WMI is blocked in this enclave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first guess is that you've got "invisible" spaces in your CSV file.  For example their is likely a trailing whitespace after the names of your servers in the CSV that your eyes of course don't see.  You can fix that either by fixing the CSV file, or using `.Trim()` on your imported strings -- i.e. `$_.Name.Trim()`

If that's not the case, or not the only issue, then this is something I've had issues with to.  When I have complicated strings like your desired `net.exe` arguments I've liked to take precautions and get extra pedantic with defining the string and not rely on PowerShell's automatic guessing of exactly where a string begins and ends.

So, instead of baking your parameters inline on your `net.exe` command line hand-craft them into a variable first, like so

```
$args = '\\' + $_.name + '/user:' + $_.name + '\Administrator' + $_.pass
```

If you `write-Host` that out you'll see that it no longer has your rogue spaces.  Indeed you may notice that it no longer has **enough** spaces, so you'll have to get a little explicit about where they belong.  For instance the above line doesn't put the proper spaces between `\\servername` and `/user`, or between the username and password, so you'd have to add that space back in, like so.

```
$args = '\\' + $_.name + ' /user:' + $_.name + '\Administrator ' + $_.pass
```

Notice the explicit spaces.

Comment: OK thanks so much, it already has worked to clean up the spaces.  So basically I should add a line above net.exe to create a "clean string" variable and use that variable in the net.exe line, correct?

Comment: Yep.  That's been my experience on playing it safe.  You don't always have to, but occasionally PowerShell's automagic guessing of how to format and space implicit strings will bite you.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I got the format right but now I am getting a "network path not found" error.  I think I'll break the whole statement up into arg variables and see if that works.

Comment: What does your CSV look like?  Perhaps your $_.Name needs to be an FQDN?  `\\server.domain.com` instead of just `\\server`?

Comment: No, it's something in the format.  I have now resolved the network path issue, but it's giving me the net.exe command format message, meaning that the way that I am passing parameters is incorrect.  Still hammering away.

Comment: My advice would be to run the `net` command by hand until you get it right.  Then replicate that in the Powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved this myself using @EdgeVB's solution.  The code ended up like this...

```
# Variables
$gssservers = Import-Csv "gssservers.csv"

$gssservers | Where-Object {$_.Tier -match "DB"} | Foreach-Object {
    $cmd1 = 'use'
    $arg1 = '\\' + $_.Name
    $arg2 = ' /user:' + $_.Name + '\Administrator '
    & net.exe $cmd1 $arg1 $arg2 $_Pass
    $cmd2 = 'query'
    $svc1 = 'mssqlserver'
    & sc.exe $arg1 $cmd2 $svc1 | Write-Host
    }
```

Not only do you need to bake the variables in beforehand, but they also cannot cross certain thresholds (for instance, if "use" and "\" are in the same variable, it breaks.